# How to load the value of a drop down to a text box when selected

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a front end project and have a set of Dropdown list where it can be selected. 
My requirement is when I select a specific dropdown name the corresponding value of it has to load in the next text box.

This is the code that I tried.

```js
$('#selseriessetupid').change(function(){
  var employeenumber =  $(':selected',this).data('lastused'); 
  $('.form-control').val(employeenumber);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 uiblock">
    <div class="form-group uicontrol editControl" data-displaytype="dropdownlist" data-fieldname="seriessetupid" data-templateitemid="8875">
      <label class="clsCaption">Employee Number</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="seriessetupid" id="selseriessetupid">
        <option value="0">Please select Status</option>
        <option data-lastused="01" value="126">FIN1</option>
        <option data-lastused="01" value="124">FIN</option>
        <option data-lastused="01" value="125">CRM</option></select></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 uiblock">
      <div class="form-group uicontrol editControl" data-displaytype="textbox" data-fieldname="employeenumber" data-templateitemid="8796">
      <label class="clsCaption">Employee ID</label> 
      <input type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" class="form-control " name="employeenumber" id="employeenumber">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of Select dropdown (#selseriessetupid) using .val() function of jquery and try setting it in the #employeenumber value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {$('#selseriessetupid').change(function(){
        $('#employeenumber').val($('#selseriessetupid').val());
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the next() method of Jquery. Try this one

```
 $('#selseriessetupid').change(function(){
          var employeenumber =  $(':selected',this).data('lastused'); 
        $(this).next('.form-control').val(employeenumber);
 });
```

**Note** It will not work in all situations cause your are using an ID selector. change it to class to work properly.